# give file permission to file on upload time

Tags: php, file-upload, file-permissions

Hello everyone i have a question with upload a file with php ocde.

please tell me with php code how can i give file permission(777) at the time of uploading .

Thanx in advance

Comment: Your PHP code does not get executed until AFTER the file upload has completed (or failed). as such, there is nothing you can do in PHP to change the file's permissions as it's uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

You should follow the best practices on the [PHP website for handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) and once you move the uploaded file to the location you want it, you can do a [chmod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) on the file to whatever permissions you want.

I would be careful using 777 permissions on any file, it can be dangerous, especially if you are running your code on a shared server.  755 is a much safer alternative for file permissions and is generally recommended.